# What is the directory if I am typing in an argument for a java program within a command line?

Tags: java, command-line, directory, command-line-arguments

Basically, I have a program which takes arguments through the command line in these parameters:

(I AM USING PUTTY)

```
./program.jar directory/file1.txt directory/file2.txt
```

But it returns saying that the directory is wrong, I would like to know what is the default directory that the argument searches from and how to locate these items through the command line

Comment: The working directory is the directory from where you started the java program. Is directory/file1.txt in the same directory like program.jar?

Answer (score 0):

It's normally the current directory of your shell (eg: value of $PWD). From within java you can find this out from [`System.getProperty("user.dir")`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html).

Keep in mind if your directory have spaces you will need to wrap it in single/double quotes or shell will split it into two arguments

Answer (score 0):

The way i understand ur question, your program takes a file as args. If the file is in the same directory as the jar, you dont need to specify the absolute path, just the file name like file1.txt. Else, you need to specify the path. If file1.txt is in other dir, you need to specify the absolute path (/mnt/dir/blabla/file.txt) in ur commandline args. Use " if the directory contains spaces such as "/mnt/dir somewhere/another/file.txt"